# Infinite recursion in object/static creation/Why is this code throwing NullPointerException?

Tags: java, recursion, static, nullpointerexception, overflow

I do not understand why the following code isn't this a causing a Stack overflow equivalent for Heap (OutOfMemoryError or something) since it is some kind of infinite recursion (is it not?). Does the static initialization provide a guard against something like this and throws NullPointerException instead?

Edit: I do not believe I was understood:
 `public static void main(String[] args)` calls a static method from `StaticClass`. Before this method, `doSmth()`, is called `StaticClass` needs to be loaded first. When a class is loaded, all the static code is ran; in the `StaticClass` class, `objClass` is a static field attributed with the value of a `new ObjClass()` and thus shouldn't be `null` (to throw `NullPointerException`). Obviously `new ObjClass()` can not be instantiated because in order to do this you need to load the `StaticClass` and this already happens when `StaticClass` is loading (thus the analogy with infinite recursion, or probably deadlock analogy). The problem is the JVM says the `objClass` is null instead of saying it couldn't initialize `new ObjClass()` because some kind of recurrent call.

In a normal case, NullPointerException is thrown because of the caller. But in this case, you can change only the callee (remove the line with the comment at the end, in the `ObjClass` constructor) and then you won't receive `NullPointerException`.

```
package pack;

public class ObjClass
{
    public ObjClass() {
        StaticClass.doSmth();//if removed, no NullPointerException
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        return "get";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StaticClass.loadStaticClass();
    }
}

class StaticClass {
    private static ObjClass objClass = new ObjClass();

    static void loadStaticClass() {
    }

    static void doSmth()             {
        System.out.println(objClass.getSomething());
    }
}
```

which gives:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at pack.ObjClass.main(ObjClass.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pack.ObjClass$StaticClass.doSmth(ObjClass.java:39)
    at pack.ObjClass.<init>(ObjClass.java:20)
    at pack.ObjClass$StaticClass.<clinit>(ObjClass.java:34)
    ... 6 more
```

Answer (score 4):

No matter how determined you are they there must be a complicated answer to this problem, is very simple. You get a NullPointerException because you dereferenced a `null` value. Nothing more.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        new A();
    }

    static class A {
        static {
            System.out.println("Start of class A initialisation, A.b is " + A.b);
        }

        static final B b = new B();

        static void method(String from) {
            System.out.println("Called a method in A from " + from + ", A.b is " + A.b);
            B.method();
        }

        static {
            System.out.println("End of class A initialisation, A.b is " + A.b);
        }
    }

    static class B {
        static {
            System.out.println("Start of class B initialisation, A.b is " + A.b);

            A.method("B static block");

            System.out.println("End of class B initialisation, A.b is " + A.b);
        }

        B() {
            A.method("B() constructor");
            System.out.println("Only after this should A.b be set.");
        }

        static void method() {
            System.out.println("Called a method in B, A.b is " + A.b);
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Start of class A initialisation, A.b is null
Start of class B initialisation, A.b is null
Called a method in A from B static block, A.b is null
Called a method in B, A.b is null
End of class B initialisation, A.b is null
Called a method in A from B() constructor, A.b is null
Called a method in B, A.b is null
Only after this should A.b be set.
End of class A initialisation, A.b is Main$B@33b7b32c
```

As you can see, one class can call another before it has finished initialising and a reference before it has been initialised can be examined and it will be `null`, even a `final` one.

---

It's throwing a NullPointerException because `objClass` hasn't been set yet.

It won't be set until you return from the constructor, but you are in the constructor, so it will have it's default value of `null`.

BTW, This is nothing like http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinite_recursion

> I do not understand why the following code isn't this a causing a Stack overflow equivalent for Heap (OutOfMemoryError or something)

They are all different errors with specific meanings.  The error thrown when a reference is used without being initialised is NullPointerException.

> Does the static initialization provide a guard against something like this and throws NullPointerException instead?

The fields doesn't have to be static for this to happen.  The same happens to non-static fields if you access them before they have been initialised.

> objClass should be instantiated when StaticClass is loaded?

It hasn't loaded, in fact it never loads because it throws an Exception before it completes.  If you where to try to use this class after this, you would get a NoClassDefError as the class failed to load.

Comment: I know the reason why a `NullPointerException` is thrown. The problem is that `objClass` should be instantiated when the `StaticClass` is loaded (and that is before actually calling `doSmth()`) and NullPointerException shouldn't be there. But when `StaticClass` is loaded `objClass` cannot be instantiated because it needs `StaticClass` to be loaded and thus some kind of infinite recursion (or a deadlock).

Comment: Or a logic bug. You have created code which cannot possibly work as each needs the other to finish first.

Comment: Yes that is true, it obviously is a logic bug. But why NullPointerException?

Comment: Either the constructor finishes nor does the class load, an Exception is thrown before that happens.

Comment: It's a NullPointerException as you try to access `objClass` before it has been set and is null which is the default value.

Comment: Regarding the comment `Either the constructor finishes nor does the class load, an Exception is thrown before that happens` I believe you meant "either the constructor doesn't finish" since you put "nor" after. But how is this possible, since the method shouldn't be evaluated before the class is loaded, and the class isn't loaded until the constructor exists and the object is created? And if the class can't be loaded, the JVM should throw this kind of exception and not `NullPointerException`. See the comments...

Comment: When a class fails to load, it throws the exception which causes it to fail to load. The method cannot be evaluated until the class has loaded, unless it is called while loading the class. Otherwise you couldn't use any method for that class while loading it.

Comment: I do not believe this is true (`The method cannot be evaluated until the class has loaded, unless it is called while loading the class.`); see the modified version. Now the method `loadStaticClass()` which is called while the class is load, does nothing, and the exception is the same. Practically `doSmth()` is called only from the constructor and since it reaches the constructor, it shouldn't throw NullPointerException.

Comment: @m3th0dman I have updated my answer with an example. You can see that classes are calling each other

Answer (score 4):

Referencing `StaticClass` instantiates `objClass`, which calls the `ObjClass` constructor, which calls `doSmth()`. This uses the reference `objClass`, but *that's not been assigned yet*, since it needs a fully constructed `objClass` to refer to.

Briefly,

```
this.x = doMethod();
```

requires `doMethod()` to complete before the reference `x` is assigned to the result.

What are you trying to do ? Or is this some sort of exercise ?

Comment: I know the Java evaluation strategy pretty well; that's not the problem. The problem is why isn't `objClass` assigned? Why doesn't it enter an infinite recursion and the JVM gives up after the first try; since there is `static ObjClass objClass = new ObjClass()`, `objClass` should be instantiated when `StaticClass` is loaded?

Comment: And how does it instantiate that reference ? By calling the ObjClass constructor. The reference isn't assigned 'til that completes (otherwise another thread could use that reference and it would point to an incomplete object)

Comment: What I do not understand is how is it possible to go to the content of `doSmth()` static method before loading the class `StaticClass`. If calling the `ObjClass` constructor doesn't finish, why isn't an exception thrown here?

Answer (score 1):

```
  private static ObjClass objClass = new ObjClass();
```

While class loading jvm tries to create instance for `ObjClass`, reference `objClass` points to `null` by the time `ObjClass` constructor called (instance creation not done yet).\

You are trying to call `objClass.getSomething()`, you are calling `getSomething()` on `null` reference which is causing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: That's what I do not understand; how can the method `doSmth()` be evaluated before the class `StaticClass` finishes loading? And by the time the class is done loading the object `objClass` should point to an object not to null; if `ObjClass` cannot be instantiated, it should throw an exception mentioning this.

Comment: Actually it says that there was a problem in the static initializer and the cause of it is `NullPointerException`.